# Async C++ Communication Library for Linux (and Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, linux, sockets, communication

I'm looking for a communications library (socket, possibly IPC as well) for usage in C++ on Linux, if possible also on Windows if it's platform independent.

It should be async. I tried the Boost Asio Library, but due to limitations we can't find a solution for, we cannot use the Asio library in our solution.

It should be an implementation where no external binary is needed to be executed separately to act as an independent server.

Does anyone of you know something that might help me with these constraints, as I don't want to implement the communication from scratch.

**Edit:**
One more limitation I forgot to mention. The communication should allow implementation independent client and server, so the messaging system should deliver and receive single messages/strings to and from dedicated sources (server s sends string str to client c)

**Edit 2:**
The Boost limitations are that with the current system, Boost Asio compiled with the MPI compiler of either MPICH2 or openmpi, especially when using mpi calls, loses several messages when trying to communicate over asio.

Comment: "limitations"? of boost asio? really? You could try ACE...

Comment: Maybe you could mention what limitations of asio you had problems with. Soo that we might suggest something without those issues?

Comment: "loses several messages"  But not all?  Just guessing, but I would blame your code rather than boost... Maybe add the code where the messages are being lost?

Comment: echoing Tom, I would also check your `async_read/write` calls, and ensure that they don't overlap on a given socket - this is a common mistake that causes corrupt read/write operations...

Comment: The only difference between working code and non-working code is using the MPI Compiler and calling MPI::Init(), So I somewhat doubt it should be an error in our code, as it works with the normal g++ and cuda compilers.

We did checks for the ports MPI runs it's messages, and the ports we use are not used by MPI. Additionally, the conenction is started successfully, and only a single port is used. If MPI would try to "hijack" that connection, I assume either all messages following the init would be killed, or we would at least see some other consequences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org), a.k.a ØMQ.

Answer (score 2):

Lot's of free stuff available, look for anything implementing AMQP (for example, and not limited to: Apache's attempt - ActiveMQ, ZeroMQ as listed above, rabbit mq [which is more complete than zero] and even Red Hat are in the game with Red Hat Messaging).

Lot's of pay for solutions ranging from Tibco to 29 West, Tervela to Solace - this depends on how much you want to fork out...

Other options, I really like include OpenDDS - different to AMQP, but again highly scalable and very good performance. (forgot to say, OpenDDS uses ACE under the covers...)

Comment: +1 for an extensive list. I'd exclude Tibco though since it requires a daemon for operation.

Comment: @Nikolai, with Rendezvous 8, I believe you now have the option of an embedded daemon..

Comment: I have read through ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ previously, but if I'm not mistaken, these two use a dedicated server that runs as a daemon. That's somewhat against the limitations I am looking for. Non-free solutions I fear are not an option I'm afraid. I may will take a look at OpenDDS though, thanks.

Comment: @Nim, thanks, I didn't know that. Anyway, Tibco is really pricy :)

Comment: @Nikolai, their pricing is small change compared to Tervela or Solace! ;)

Comment: I didn't know Solace pricing, but the people I worked with there made a very good impression - knew their stuff and were quick to find and fix the issues.